# Why doesn't JavaScript set h:inputHidden value?

Tags: javascript, jsf, hidden-field

I saw many examples and did the same but I cannot set value with JavaScript.

There is my code

```
<h:form id="listPlacesForm">
  <h:inputHidden id="hiddenMapCenter" value="#{userPlaces.center}" />
</h:form>
```

and JavaScript

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findPosition);
} else
    error('Geo Location is not supported');

function findPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert('Start')
    var str = lat + ", " + lng;
    var elem = document.getElementById('listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter')
    alert(str)
    elem.value = 'asfsf'
    alert('It works!' + str);
}
```

All these code works except line: `elem.value = 'asfsf'`
I tried:  `elem.value = 'sfd'`,  `elem.value = "asfd"`,  `elem.value = str`

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**
Generated HTML

```
<form id="mainTabId:listPlacesForm" 
      name="mainTabId:listPlacesForm" method="post"
      action="/DarkComm/app/settings?execution=e3s1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <input type="hidden" name="mainTabId:listPlacesForm" value="mainTabId:listPlacesForm" />
      <input id="mainTabId:listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter"
             type="hidden"          
             name="mainTabId:listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter" value="" />
    <input type="hidden"   name="javax.faces.ViewState"
           id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="e3s1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try just using `hiddenMapCenter` as the id in `document.getElementById`  instead of `listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter`?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the same id?

Comment: How did you confirm that the value is not set? There's nothing in the code that would actually use it.

Comment: @Juhana No, I haven't   
Also I tried change value for `input type="text"`, `p:inputText`

Comment: Please show the generated HTML instead of the JSF code (right click -> view source in the browser).

Comment: How do you invoke that JavaScript function and when?

Comment: @Juhana, message after line `elem.value = 'asfsf'` did not invoke

Comment: You also forgot to terminate several statements using a semicolon. Please be explicit terminating them and do not leave it to the JavaScript parser.

Comment: @Juhana I added generated HTML already

Comment: @Tiny when page load

Comment: Ok, and from that HTML you'll notice that the element's actual id is...?

Comment: @Tiny, after adding semicolon nothing changed

Comment: @Juhana actual id is: `mainTabId:listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter` :)

Comment: How is the form `id` prepended, `mainTabId:listPlacesForm`? What is `mainTabId`? This is not the exact rendered HTML code based on the first XHTML snippet. Did you change it yourself?

Comment: Ok. It works with next line: 

`var elem = document.getElementById('mainTabId:listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter');`

Comment: @Tiny It is tabView around all these elements
I thought if I found element I could change its value

Comment: I guessed afterwards :). Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Change this:

```
      var elem = document.getElementById('listPlacesForm:hiddenMapCenter')
```

To this:

```
      var elem = document.getElementById('hiddenMapCenter')
```

Comment: JSF prepends `id`s with respective parent components unless `prependId` associated with `<h:form>` is set to false.

Comment: Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeiTruhin/2sops8br/

Result: http://i.imgur.com/Oac9CSl.png